# a question about Brooks' Theorem for $\Delta =4$

Tags: graph-colorings

From Brooks' Theorem, we know that

if a graph $G$ satisfies that $\Delta (G)=4$ and there is no $5$-clique in $G$, then $\chi (G)\leq 4$.

And it is easy to find a counterexample to the following:

if a graph $G$ satisfies that $\Delta (G)=4$ and there is no $4$-clique in $G$, then $\chi (G)\leq 3$.

I want to ask whether the following conclusion is right or please give a counterexample!

if a graph $G$ satisfies that $\Delta (G)=4$ and there is no $3$-clique in $G$, then $\chi (G)\leq 3$.

Comment: It's Brooks's theorem, not Brook's.

Comment: No, it is Brooks' Theorem.

Comment: Blass's opinion agrees with @bof's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.

Try this in Sage:

```
g = Graph("K?BD@hWFf_HW")
g.show()
```

[image]

Then

```
g.chromatic_number()
```

to confirm.

In general, it seems that imposing "triangle-free" does not seem to materially alter the chromatic behaviour of a class of graphs.

Comment: Johansson proved that every triangle-free graph with maximum degree $\Delta$ is $O(\Delta/\log\Delta)$-colourable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your counterexample!Gordon Royle. Would you please look at this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198811/the-choosing-of-an-independent-set-in-a-specific-k-partite-graph and give a counterexample?

Comment: This is the Mycielski graph of $C_5$.